# Mongo Shell Support For Negative Lookbehind RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, shell, negative-lookbehind

Does Mongo Shell not support negative look-behind?  Example:

```
'aaabbb'.replace(/(?<!a)b/g, 'X')
```

> Replace all `b` not preceeded by `a` with `X`

Browser console output:

```
aaabXX
```

Right. However if I put that into `test.js` and do `mongo < ./test.js` I get:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.23
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.23
2020-08-14T10:15:13.199-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid regexp group @(shell):1:17
bye
```

I can't find any definitive documentation on what Mongo shell supports insofar as ECMAScript...but it appears it doesn't support negative look-behind (at least). What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It is working in new MongoDB Shell,

```
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Using MongoDB:      4.4.0
Using Mongosh Beta: 0.1.0

> 'aaabbb'.replace(/(?<!a)b/g, 'X')
aaabXX
```

For more information about mongosh, please see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) and [download](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell), if you are on macOS with homebrew:

```
$ brew tap mongodb/brew
$ brew install mongosh
```

> I don't know why its not working in local CMD, i tried in [web mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/index.html) v4.2.0 but also not working.